# inkscape from command prompt

Tags: graphics, conversion, automation, eps

I was looking at the answer to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-are-good-ways-to-convert-eps-to-pdf) (converting EPS to PDF) where they suggested using Inkscape to convert EPS to PDF images. I need the exact same thing. Using the GUI, it works like a charm. Since I have about 200 images to convert, is there a way to automate this process? Or at least run it via command line so that I can do this process faster?

I am a newbie in batch files and such, so please try to elaborate on the procedure needed.

Comment: Windows. When I use that command, it says that

'inkscape' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you asked the support of the programm? What does the manual said?